# How to get Android Emulator type with ADB

Tags: android

I need to programmatically get the type of Android Emulator that's running using ADB (or any other method).  ADB gives me everything I need for devices and I can get things like the Android build (4.4.2, etc.) for an Emulator but what I need is a way of telling if the Emulator device name is Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S, etc.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this?

```
adb devices
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That lists the devices with their IDs, but that's not what I need.  I've already gone through everything in adb shell getprop and it doesn't look like any of those properties tell me what I need.

Comment: @user2666022 may I ask why you need the name of it?

Comment: This is just for logging purposes.  I'm writing something that gathers data about the target device.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what I was looking for, but if you run "android list avd" you'll get something like this:

Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: AVD_for_Nexus_One_by_Google
  Device: Nexus One (Google)
    Path: C:\Users\lukewest.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_One_by_Google.avd
  Target: Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
 Tag/ABI: default/armeabi-v7a

### Skin: 480x800

```
Name: AVD_GalaxyNexus_MultiDeviceHybridApps
```

Device: Galaxy Nexus (Google)
    Path: C:\Users\lukewest.android\avd\AVD_GalaxyNexus_MultiDeviceHybridApps.avd
  Target: Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
 Tag/ABI: default/armeabi-v7a
    Skin: WVGA800
    BlankCordovaApp9